# Как следовать правилу "на каждый if - свой else" в списках, если неизвестно что делает библиотека с View?

Tags: android, recyclerview, picasso

Я знаю как работать со списками, например в зависимости от чего-то нужно не только что-то делать с `View`, но и... короче, вот, к примеру, если есть ссылка то показываем кнопку загрузки...

```
if(file.getLink() == null){
    btn_download.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
else{
    btn_download.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Или укороченная запись (не важен `if/else`, главное, учитывать оба случая)

```
btn_download.setVisibility( file.getLink() == null ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
```

Это, конечно, все ясно, но как быть с `View`, которую ты отдаешь библиотеке? Ведь неизвестно что она там с ним делает. Вот я и столкнулся с этой проблемой. У меня список фотографий, загружаемых через библиотеку `Picasso`. Причем, если фотографии нет, то нужно показывать плэйсхолдер. Я реализовал так

```
if(photo == null)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            Picasso.with(ctx).
            load(photo).
            resize(photoWidth, photoHeight).
            into(photo_iv);
        }
```

В `if` пробовал устанавливать картинку через `setImageResource`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Picasso` использует `setImageBitmap`, так что нужно загружать (но лучше один раз, а потом просто использовать `Bitmap`

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.yourimage);
```

Но я реализовал более коротко, велосипед, конечно

```
Picasso.with(ctx).
        load(photo == null ? "*" : photo).
        error(R.drawable.no_image).
        resize(photoWidth, photoHeight).
        into(photo_iv);
```

Тоесть, если ссылки нет то намеренно передаю несуществующую ссылку, тем самым вызывая ошибку :D